# Amplify / Cognito : refresh session variables after updating user attributes (angular)

Tags: angular, variables, session, amazon-cognito

My function used to update attributes :

```
updateUserInfo(user, attributes) {

  Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, attributes)
    .then(
      result => {
        console.log(result); // SUCCESS
      }
    )
    .catch(
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
}
```

So the result is `SUCCESS` and in my AWS Cognito service, on the page of the specific user, I can see that the attributes have been changed. So the update is working fine in Cognito.

But when I refresh the page of my angular app after that this update function has been called, the old attributes are still there, and not the new ones. So I can think that a refresh of the current user sessions variables is required to get the new attributes, how to do that ?

Note : Something I don't understand is that on my page of my angular app which displays the user attributes, I do a GET request to Amazon to get user attributes. So if before getting info these information an update has been done, why am I still getting the old attributes ?

Answer (score 7):

Current solution is to call `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({ bypassCache: true })` after `Auth.updateUserAttributes()`.